# Scala conditional sum of elements in a filtered tuples list

Tags: list, scala, filter, sum

I'm new to Scala and need a little help about how to combine
filters and sum on a list of tuples.

What I need is the sum of integers of a filtered tuples list which
essentially the answer to the question:

What is the sum of all set weights?

The result should be 20 for the sample list below

The list is pretty simple:

```
     val ln = List( ("durationWeight" , true, 10),
                    ("seasonWeight"   , true, 10),
                    ("regionWeight"   , false, 5),
                     ("otherWeight"   , false, 5)
```

Filtering the list according to the Boolean flag is a simple:

```
     val filtered = ln.filter { case(name, check, value) => check == true  }
```

which returns me the wanted tuples. Getting the sum of all them seems to work 
with a map followed by sum:

```
  val b = filtered.map{case((name, check, value) ) => value}.sum
```

Which returns me the wanted sum of all set weights.

However, how do I do all that in one step combining filter, map and sum, 
ideally in an elegant one liner?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Marvin.Hansen! Just as a tip for the future, it's not necessary to edit your question to reflect that the question was solved or include the solution - that functionality is built-in already by marking the answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ln.collect{ case (_, true, value) => value }.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for the heck of it:

```
(0 /: ln)((sum,x) => if (x._2) sum + x._3 else sum)
```

Comment: That will surely be faster than collect and then sum.